# My site is vulnerable to this script..How do i patch it?

Tags: php, javascript, html

One guy tried to exploit it using this script

```
http://www.searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28String.fromCharCode%2872%29+String.fromCharCode%28105%29%29;%3C/script%3E
```

How do i stop it ?

And he also said that it is vulnerable to XSS and LPI...Please help me stop it.

Thanking You,

Comment: Oh god, you didn't actually [take my advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788572/are-there-any-vulnerabilities-of-this-site-closed) did you?

Comment: @fredley - that's comedy gold right there

Comment: What does LPI stand for?

Comment: @fredley - thats doesn't even have such a forum !!!

Comment: @Brandon: Pick on: http://www.acronymfinder.com/LPI.html Personally, I think this site might be vulnerable to Lysinuric Protein Intolerance

Comment: @Frustrated, okay, let me rephrase. What does it stand for in the context of this question?

Comment: @Brandon: I have no idea. I've never seen "LPI" in this context. I'm guessing the "I" is for "Injection", "L" maybe is for "Link"?, "P"... Umm... can't think of anything right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick solution is to:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($blah); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $blah; ?>
```

The long solution is to read a book on web site security.

Answer (score 6):

You need to HTML-encode all user-entered data that you output, including the user's search string.

To be safe, HTML-encode **all** values that are not explicitly meant to be HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how that is a search query string, I'm guessing you're pulling the value directly from the query string and re-displaying it to the user?

Something along the lines of "Your search of 'something' returned 0 results"?

You need to encode any user entered data before displaying it.

Comment: Yah thats exactly what I'm doing !! So is it safe ?? And how to counter it ?

Comment: No, it's not safe. Anytime you're displaying a value that is user entered, you need to encode it. You can't trust them to enter in harmless data. See Novikovs answer for an easy way to fix your problem.